# MySQL "Writing to net" taking forever on a local machine

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I have a MySQL query that looks like this:

```
SELECT distinct(time), sens3
FROM inodes_data
WHERE i_id = 12002
  AND time > '2013-04-01 00:00:00'
```

When executing the query through a C# program, it takes more than a couple of minutes, and returns some 76k rows.

When executing the query from the MySQL CLI, it returns the same number of rows nearly instantaneously.

When I watch the process list, the vast majority of the time it takes through the C# program is in a state called "Writing to net"

I have googled, and googled, and found nothing but a good understanding of what the state means. It does not make sense (to me), given that the database is at "localhost".

So I have decided to come to my good friends at SO to see if any guidance can be offered. Thanks.

Comment: What does your query string look like? Also, what is the size of the `sens3` column?

Comment: The query string is printed in the question above, and there are 107456 rows total that match the "i_id"

Comment: Writing to net  means MySQL is writing data to the network socket. Does it always take longer from the C# program? Are you displaying all the records in the c# app?

Comment: I understand what it means, and unfortunately it does take longer from the C# application. I am using a mysqldatareader to iterate over the records.

Comment: If you are iterating 76.000 records, that is probably what is taking so long since its writing it to the c# app. Can you just try to add `LIMIT 1000` to the query to see if it goes faster.

Comment: Of course it is going to get faster, because its writing less to the network socket. I am a career programmer, and I am very familiar with how to debug a C# application. So please take my word when I say the time is not taken in the iteration, as the iterations do not start until the fetch (which hangs a while on "writing to net" is completed.

Comment: Afaik, if you are not connecting to the DB externally you shouldn't get that status. This status should only occur if it has to use the network to transfer data -which in your case, localhost, isn't. Can you try the same with a different language and see if it has the same issue? Could be a C# bug.

Comment: May not be relevant since C# isn't my thing - but I've found MySQL under Windows can get sulky if you connect to it as 'localhost' rather than by IP address '127.0.0.1' in your connection string - it works but it runs slow as hell.

Comment: I have written other programs using the same code snippets across 4 or 5 of them and never had the issue. The variable in this case is the hardware on which I am developing on. I have programs that read in 1.6 million rows or greater, and it doesn't even take this long. When I run the same Query from MySQL workbench, it is very fast. Also ran the query throw MySQL workbench on a remote server with an exact copy of the database and it was fast. Ran the C# app against the remote database, and it was slow.

Comment: Also C# isn't my thing as well, but are there settings for C# installation you can match to a machine which works fine, could be a difference in settings that is causing this.

Comment: If the db server has a public IP address, you may be inadvertently connecting there. Unless you're familiar with troubleshooting name resolution, try connecting via IP address instead of hostname.

Comment: @MarcusAdams, have tried both.

Comment: "Writing to net" makes perfect sense, because **IP sockets** are not different between the local computer and the other side of the world. Unix socket or a **named pipe** on Windows are more efficient. Could you please comment on CPU load — which processes are active in the task manager? And please add .net and c# tags to properly position the question.

Comment: could you show how do you initialize db connection please?

Comment: could you try and execute your program from a different computer? Meaning, if you currently work on Computer A, take your program to some other computer (B) and execute it against the database on A. Also, please post the code that shows how you get the results and iterate through them.